# Master detail example of Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can anyone point me to a master detail implementation in Rails? I Googled but couldn't find any good example sites.

Comment: What is a master detail implementation?

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to start with a [acts_as_tree](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Acts/Tree/ClassMethods.html) model but the exact implementation depends a lot on what you want as an end result ;)